# Python plotting log want 10000 not 10^4 on x/y axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, axis, logarithm

Trying to make good looking plots and can't make the scale of the two axis how i want them.
[How the plot looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilUnF.png). I want it to say 10000 instead of 10^4 and 100 instead of 10^2. Any suggestions?
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = (100, 1000,10000)
b = (1, 10,100)
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
```

[Plot how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilUnF.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code should work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

a = (100, 1000,10000)
b = (1, 10,100)

ax = plt.axes(xscale='log', yscale='log')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.plot(a,b)
```

Note that there was a problem with the code in the question: the second line that has

```
plt.xscale('log')
```

should have been

```
plt.yscale('log')
```